# Create views from field values Drupal-7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

So if I understand correctly I have will a few content types "Category", "Sub Category", "Product", "Images" I am just not sure how I will associate the content types with each other to build views. So based on my structure below: I would create a Category name "Home" with the "Category" type. The category would have a view that shows all Sub Categories that are associated with this view "Category". This is my question: When I go to create my new Sub Category "Furniture" how do I associate it with the view that is on my "Home" Category page? And so on with the Products which will all belong to sub category and the images will all belong to a product. Can I use a custom field that the user adds a string?

```
Home (category)
-Furniture (sub category)

-Sofa(product)
-images

-Lamp(product)
-images

Outdoors(category)
-Deck Furniture(sub category)

-Table(product)
-images

-Fire-pit(product)
-images
```

I am sure this was confusing so if anyone has questions please ask. Any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing because it seems that there are two parts to it that aren't clearly defined.

If you're looking to relate content to each other, check out the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references).

As for creating the display you're looking for, the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) is likely what you're looking for.  There is also a [Views Hierarchy module](http://drupal.org/project/views_hierarchy) which you may need but is currently unavailable for Drupal 7.